# how do I release a struct from memory and arrays within them

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

I want to know how I can release a struct properly from memory and completely wipe it. I also need to wipe arrays or values within this struct. I tried just overwriting the struct with new data everytime the data changed but I observed a steady rise in memory use until I get a memory warning so I think my safest bet is to completely wipe the data first and then write to it again.

```
    typedef struct {


        SInt16  *array1;     
        SInt16  *array2;    

    } myStruct, *myStructPtr;


 myStructArray        myStruct[16];

    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)

    {
        myStruct[i].array1 =
        (AudioUnitSampleType *) calloc (asize, sizeof (SInt16));

        myStruct[i].array2 =
        (AudioUnitSampleType *) calloc (asize, sizeof (SInt16));

    }

   free(myStructArray) // throws SIGBART error
```

Comment: suggestion: myStruct[i].array1 = calloc( asize, sizeof *myStruct[i].array1 ).  No cast and sizeof object rather than sizeof( type ).

Comment: What do you mean by "wipe", and why do you think you need to do it?

Comment: The reasons for William's suggestions are 1) casts suppress compile-time warnings that can indicate runtime errors; they should be avoided whenever possible 2) repeating the type is error-prone -- if the type of the arrays is changed but the calloc argument isn't, you'll allocate the wrong amount which can result in a hard-to-find crash. It violates the DRY ("don't repeat yourself") principle.

Comment: @jim . When I enter a view I extract audio data into these arrays. When I leave the view and reenter it I want to "wipe" these arrays so that they can be filled with new audio data. I tried just re calloc the arrays but it was causing my memory usage to climb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't `malloc` or `calloc` `myStructArray` so you shouldn't `free` it. Loop over the elements and `free` `myStruct[i].array1` and `array2`

```
for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        free(myStruct[i].array1);
        free(myStruct[i].array2);
    }
```

The general rule is simple - `free` what you `malloc/calloc/realloc/strdup/other allocs`, nothing more or less. Note that `alloca` is an exemption - it allocates on stack, so you should never free what you got from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
myStructArray myStruct[16];
```

`myStruct` is an array of objects created on stack. You can not call `free` on it. `free` needs to be called on resources acquired from free store ( using malloc, realloc etc., ). Instead you need call free on struct members `array1`, `array2`.